# Shader applied to Texture is not showed in GLSLES

Tags: shaders, glsl

I'm trying to learn the basic of shaders following basic tutorials in Ogre.

I use GLSL ES 2.0 #version 100

I think I have a basic concept problem. I'm trying to render a model + texture without make modifications to be sure that is working, and then start with modifications.

I have the following material:

```
fragment_program Basic_ps_glsles glsles
{
    source Basic_ps.glsles
    profiles glsles

    default_params
    {
        param_named tex0 int 0
    }
}

vertex_program Basic_vs_glsles glsles
{
    source Basic_vs.glsles
    profiles glsles

    default_params
    {       
        param_named_auto mvp_matrix viewproj_matrix 
    }
}



material Penguin
{
    technique
    {
        pass
        {
            ambient 0.5 0.5 0.5
            diffuse 0.5 0.5 0.5

            fragment_program_ref Basic_ps_glsles glsles
            {
            }

            vertex_program_ref Basic_vs_glsles glsles
            {
            }

            texture_unit
            {
                texture penguin.jpg
                tex_coord_set 0
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And I apply the next Vertex shader:

```
#version 100 

//http://www.widget-101.com/opengl/curso-basico-opengl/opengl-glsl/

precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 position;        
attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 multiTexCoord0;

uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;
uniform mat4 texture_matrix;    

varying vec4 frag_color;
varying vec2 texCoord;          


void main()                    
{
    gl_Position = mvp_matrix*position;
    vec4 transformed_tex_coord = mvp_matrix * multiTexCoord0;   
    texCoord = transformed_tex_coord.st;
}
```

And then the next Fragment Shader:

```
#version 100


precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D tex0;

varying vec4 frag_color;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(tex0,texCoord);
    gl_FragColor = color;   //vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // frag_color;
}
```

But The texture is not applied to the pinguin. It appear totally black. I think is a problem with the texture coordinates. What I doing wrong with the texture coordinates?

Comment: There could be two resons. 
1 : your texture input is not valid, thus making the texture black.
2 : calculating uv cordinates is not done via multiplying them with model_view_projectionMatrix. you should only pass them on. beacuse they are alredy in the correct space.

Comment: 1º The texture works fine if I don't use the shaders. 2º Is then the viewproj_matrix the problem calculating the uv coordinates in my case? How I must calculate the coordinates?

Comment: often you calculate them like this : vec4 transformed_tex_coord = multiTexCoord0; You dont transform them at all. they are only a value between 0 and 1. 0 beeing the right corner and 1 beeing the left. or viseversa depending on devices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the texture coordinates. Ogre store the data in attribute vec4 uv0; So in the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = mvp_matrix*position;
texCoord = uv0.st;
```

Solve the problem